# Pulse-oximeter USB A UART cable to a USB C data download cable required. I need the USB A UART output to interface with a USB C cable

Tags: uart

I need to make an interface cable using a USB – FTDI to TTL 3.3V serial UART converter cable connected to a USB C plug.

Could anyone help with the connection of the FTDI UART output to the USB C plug?

Comment: You mean you want to know how to connect FTDI to a type-c usb connector since it has some additional pins?

Comment: Why do you need to make it? Why existing cables you can already buy won't work?

Comment: I cannot seem to find an existing cable with these connections. I did once have a UART cable thar terminated in a mini b plug, this was for an older pulse-oximeter.

Answer (score 0):

Here you could find something very similar:
[image: FTDI 232RL Schematic]
Source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/FTDI-232RL-schematic-FTDI_fig6_332303244

In this particular case, the USB port is a B-type.
For the USB C type, you have to connect the same signal (Vbus, D-, D+ and GND to the FT232RL IC (or similar).

Here you can find the pinout of the USB-C port:
[image: USB Type-C plug pinout]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USB_Type-C_plug_pinout.svg

Please, let me know if you find it useful.

Comment: For USB-C you also need to take care of the CC1 & CC2 pins.